# Return to last URL entered after successfull login in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have function login on its successful function control goes to `dashboard/index`. Suppose a user enter `leads/index` the page come back to login due to access rules defined, i just want that **after successful login control goes to last URL entered** i.e. `leads/index`.

Comment: When you logging out the user checking access rules. Pass the current url in the query string. And just redirect back to that if they logged in successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
... Controller extends CController (){
...
public function init() {

   if($this->isValidForRedirectRequest(Yii::app()->request)){
       Yii::app()->user->returnUrl = Yii::app()->request->requestUri;
   }
}
...

public function isValidForRedirectRequest(){
   /*something validations of request, like isAjax or other */
}
}...




... LoginController()...{

if($authIdentity->authenticate()) $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
...

}
```

Comment: This line of code worked for me. Thank you for your help.
$this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not how it's supposed to be done. All you need is to add `Yii::app()->user->loginRequired()` to the action that requires a login (or use access rules). Yii does the rest for you. No need to mess around with redirects manually!

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work:

```
Yii::app()->user->setReturnUrl("Your url");
```

then use,

```
$this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
```

to redirect.

or you can also take help of session.

before login set

```
Yii::app()->session['beforelogin'] = Yii::app()->request->requestUri;`
```

just before redirecting after login check

```
if(isset(Yii::app()->session['beforelogin'])) {
  $this->redirect(Yii::app()->session['beforelogin']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think most simple answer for this question is this code:

```
$this->redirect(Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer);
```

use this code that's it.

Answer (score 1):

**For Yii2.**

In controller in method `actionLogin()` use this:

```
if (Yii::$app->user->getReturnUrl() == '/') {
  return $this->redirect('dashboard/index');
} else {
  return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->user->getReturnUrl());
}
```

It will check if the login is coming from home page (`getReturnUrl() == '/'`), then after login it will redirect you to `dashboard/index` page. Otherwise, it will redirect to requested page.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl)` in your `SiteController`.

```
public function actionLogin() {
    $this->setTheme();
    $this->layout = '//layouts/login';
    $model = new LoginForm;

    // if it is ajax validation request
    if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === 'login-form') {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // collect user input data
    if (isset($_POST['LoginForm'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if ($model->validate() && $model->login())
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
    }
    // display the login form
    $this->render('login', array('model' => $model));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to control that behaviour by sessions (pagination for example, ...) but,

```
return $this->goBack();
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a condition when actionID=auth, so it works only when action is auth which opens Google auth window.

```
public function beforeAction($action){
  if ($action->id == 'auth' && Yii::$app->request->referrer !== null) {
        Yii::$app->session->set('returnUrl', Yii::$app->request->referrer);
  }
 return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```